# Preventing serialization of attributes while passing via jquery ajax web service call

Tags: asp.net, web-services, serialization, attributes

I m making a webservice call via jquery ajax to fetch a list of Forum Threads. I have a class with the name "ForumInfo" which has a list of attributes specified.
[image]

However when I make the web service call, I want to limit the number of attributes that is passed from server. But a slew of(all) the attributes are serialized in the ajax call.
[image]

Is there a way to stop the serialization of the unnecessary attributes in such scenarios?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [[ScriptIgnoreAttribute]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx)?